# PDF Version of Completed Form to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, cognito-forms, pdf

Is there a way to automatically have a PDF version of a submitted form saved in Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can have a PDF version of the submitted form sent to Google Drive by using [Zapier](https://zapier.com/). You will need to be on a paid plan in order for this information to be included and sent over to Zapier.

Comment: Thank you! :). What I can't figure out is how to set up the template or whatever in Zapier.   I get how to connect with Zapier, select the correct form, link it to google drive etc, but I don't know how to basically say "take the PDF print of this form submission and save it in the google drive folder I selected."  Can you advise?